# Is there any PC CAS descendant from "Derive" by Soft Warehouse/TI?

Tags: cas

```
*//in case of headless automoderation: it is **NOT** a recommendation
of some software. It is a search for ANY descendant software, which was
sold and abandoned 30 years ago. At the moment I know no comparable tool
with the same syntax and capabilities. There should be some//*
```

In the 90s, Derive CAS was very popular, because of simplicity and low system requirements. Derive For Windows 6, the last version, used true windows interface, offering quick but high precision graphics, and fine toolset. For everyday engineering problems, it is still more productive using Derive, than overbloated and hard to script Maxima or Wolfram. But it is old. Too old.

Is there any modern software using a descendant engine and syntax of Derive for PC? I know, there are TI calculators, but I want a PC-solution.

Comment: How great would it be to have Derive as a native app for mobile devices. 25 years ago I bought an HP 95LX calculator that runs DOS just so I can run Derive on it as a calculator. It was spectacularly fast and powerful at the time, with just the text UI, so I can only imagine today with a modern UI how geat it would be.

Comment: PS. I still use DfW 4 for engineering to this day, mostly for symbolic linear algebra which I find far easier to work with than Maxima, Matlab Symbolic Toolbox, Maple, Julia SymEngine, SymPy, or worse MathCAD symbolics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately no such computer algrebra system (CAS) is available. Texas Instruments (TI) bought all rights to Derive from Soft Warehouse, used a subset of its capabilities in their calculator software and TI-Nspire PC CAS, and discontinued Derive as a PC software.

If someone wrote a Derive-like frontend to SymPy, that might already be quite close to what you seek.